# How to query an object in an array embedded in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am currently working on an application that takes control of Projects, which have Meetings and that these meetings have Participants.

I want to consult a Participant by his `nomina` field.

**Structure for a project document object:**

```
 {
       "id":"5c1b0616a0441f27f022bfdc",
       "name":"Project Test",
       "area":"Area",
       "date":"2019-01-01",
       "meetings":[
          {
             "id":"5c1b073d445707834699ce97",
             "objetive":"Objetive",
             "fecha":"2019-01-01",
             "participants":[
                {
                   "nomina":1,
                   "name":"Person 1",
                   "role":"Rol1",
                   "area":"area1",
                   "signature":null
                },
                {
                   "nomina":2,
                   "name":"Person 2",
                   "role":"rol 2",
                   "area":"área 2",
                   "signature":null
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

**Expected behavior**

I want to consult a Participant by `nomina` field knowing the `id` of the Project and also knowing the `id` of the Meeting.

**Expected output**

Having:

- `id` Project = 5c1b0616a0441f27f022bfdc
- `id` Meeting = 5c1b073d445707834699ce97
- `nomina` Participant = 1

It's expected that the query will return me:

```
{    
"nomina":1,             
"name":"Person 1",
"role":"Rol1",
"area":"area1",
"signature":null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For not so huge number of meetings in every document if you want to get the exact document stated, you can do this pipeline, it is straight forward:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
       {
            $match: {
              id:"5c1b0616a0441f27f022bfdc"             
            }
        },          {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$meetings"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$meetings.participants"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
              "meetings.id":"5c1b073d445707834699ce97",
              "meetings.participants.nomina":1

            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: "$meetings.participants"
            }
        }
    ]);
```

If you would have over thousands of elements in meetings then I'd suggest adding another match to meetings or grouping meetings and project IDs.
But if you just want to get the document containing what you want it is just a simple find query:

```
db.collection.find({id:"5c1b0616a0441f27f022bfdc","meetings.id":"5c1b073d445707834699ce97","meetings.participants.nomina":1 });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. `db.collection.find({id:"5c1b0616a0441f27f022bfdc","meetings.id":"5c1b073d445707834699ce97","meetings.participants.nomina":1 });` this will always return me the entire document? I ran the example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ThpIFj0-2V-)

Comment: Yes, that would bring the whole document containing the conditions you want, but if you have at most a couple of thousand elements in "meetings" array, you can easily go with aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, and now that I know the `Participant` with `nomina`= 1, how could modify his `signature` field?

Comment: You mean you want to update that document ?
https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays
Something like this should work: 
db.collection.update({id:"5c1b0616a0441f27f022bfdc","meetings.id":"5c1b073d445707834699ce97","meetings.participants.nomina":1 },{$set:{"meetings.participants.$$.signature":1122}}, false, true )

Comment: It throws me an error: `"errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'participants' in element {meetings: [ { id: '5c1b073d445707834699ce97', objetive: "Objetive", fecha: "2019-01-01", participants: [ { nomina: 1, name: "Person 1", role: "Rol1", area: "area1", signature: "" }, { nomina: 2, name: "Person 2", role: "rol 2", area: "area 2", signature: "" } ] } ]}"`

Comment: I think that the feature `$$` is only available to Nodechef Cloud Search instance.

Comment: Oh yup, sorry about that, what is the tool or language that your are working with mongo on ?

Comment: I'm working with Spring Boot and Kotlin. I was trying to test the queries from the command line first.